# Magento 2.2 showing error on order place "no such entry for orderid="

Tags: magento2.2

In Magento 2.2 When i click on place order, i am getting this error

> no such entry for orderid=

Please anybody can sugguest me how can i solve it.

Thank you

Comment: Are you using any shipping or checkout extension?

Comment: Hii Sukumar, No i am not using any third party extension.